# How can I display items across multiple pages when swiping in GridView QML?

Tags: qt, gridview, qml

I'm unable to achieve the following:

While swiping the grid view, a set of items should scroll as a page, and the next set of items should be displayed in the next page.

For example, I have total of 20 items, First page should display 10, and second should display 10. If it is more than 20 items, then dynamically, a 3rd page should be created for the rest of the items.

Here's my attempt :

**GridExample.qml**

```
import QtQml 2.12
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQml.Models 2.12

GridView {
    id: root
    width: 320; height: 200
    cellWidth: 80; cellHeight: 80

    displaced: Transition {
        NumberAnimation { properties: "x,y"; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad }
    }
    flow: Grid.TopToBottom

//! [0]
    model: DelegateModel {
//! [0]
        id: visualModel
        model: ListModel {
            id: colorModel
            ListElement { color: "blue" }
            ListElement { color: "green" }
            ListElement { color: "red" }
            ListElement { color: "yellow" }
            ListElement { color: "orange" }
            ListElement { color: "purple" }
            ListElement { color: "cyan" }
            ListElement { color: "magenta" }
            ListElement { color: "chartreuse" }
            ListElement { color: "aquamarine" }
            ListElement { color: "indigo" }
            ListElement { color: "black" }
            ListElement { color: "lightsteelblue" }
            ListElement { color: "violet" }
            ListElement { color: "grey" }
            ListElement { color: "springgreen" }
            ListElement { color: "salmon" }
            ListElement { color: "blanchedalmond" }
            ListElement { color: "forestgreen" }
            ListElement { color: "pink" }
            ListElement { color: "navy" }
            ListElement { color: "goldenrod" }
            ListElement { color: "crimson" }
            ListElement { color: "teal" }
            ListElement { color: "springgreen" }
            ListElement { color: "salmon" }
            ListElement { color: "blanchedalmond" }
            ListElement { color: "forestgreen" }
            ListElement { color: "pink" }
            ListElement { color: "navy" }
            ListElement { color: "goldenrod" }
            ListElement { color: "crimson" }
            ListElement { color: "teal" }
        }
//! [1]
        delegate: DropArea {
            id: delegateRoot
            required property color color

            width: 80; height: 80

            onEntered: function(drag) {
                visualModel.items.move((drag.source as Icon).visualIndex, icon.visualIndex)
            }

            property int visualIndex: DelegateModel.itemsIndex

            Icon {
                id: icon
                dragParent: root
                visualIndex: delegateRoot.visualIndex
                color: delegateRoot.color
            }
        }
//! [1]
    }
}
```

**Icon.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: icon
    required property Item dragParent

    property int visualIndex: 0
    width: 72
    height: 72
    anchors {
        horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    }
    radius: 3

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "white"
        text: parent.visualIndex
    }

    DragHandler {
        id: dragHandler
    }

    Drag.active: dragHandler.active
    Drag.source: icon
    Drag.hotSpot.x: 36
    Drag.hotSpot.y: 36

    states: [
        State {
            when: dragHandler.active
            ParentChange {
                target: icon
                parent: icon.dragParent
            }

            AnchorChanges {
                target: icon
                anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined
                anchors.verticalCenter: undefined
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Because you use `GridView.flow: GridView.TopToBottom` it does scroll horizontally. However, there is no concept of pages, you can scroll as small as large as you like. Can you clarify what is wrong with this, and how you intend to implement pages?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I want it to scroll horizontally! When the item is filled in the first page I don't want the scroll, I want the other items to be displayed in another page instead. Do I have to use two grid views instead? Can't this be done in one? Thank you!

Comment: This question feels similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366265/how-to-filter-a-delegatemodel-with-more-than-one-different-filter-groups-qml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for a mockup, you could use a surrounding `ListView` with `orientation: ListView.Horizontal` and `snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem` to mimick a paging swipe. Within each ListView delegate, you could implement an instance of `GridView` each GridView displaying 10 records from a master list. For 30 items, I create 3 pages (`model: 3`) which 10 items being displayed per page. Below is a crude example of this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    property var dat: {
        var list = [ ];
        for (let ch of "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234".match(/./g)) {
            list.push(ch);
        }
        return list;
    }
    ListView {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 320
        height: 200
        model: 3
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        clip: true
        delegate: Frame {
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: ListView.view.height
            property int pageIndex: index
            GridView {
                anchors.fill: parent
                cellWidth: 70
                cellHeight: 70
                model: 10
                delegate: Label {
                    width: 65
                    height: 65
                    property int itemIndex: index + pageIndex * 10
                    text: dat[itemIndex]
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    background: Rectangle { border.color: "red" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thank you, this solution is almost efficient! Can we also do the same thing with drag and drop conditions as I have used it in the above code mentioned.