# How to filter a delegatemodel with more than one different filter groups qml

Tags: qml, kde-plasma

I have a `ListView` with `model`, number 6 and horizontal scrolling .Inside `ListView`  there is a `GridView` with  `model` a `ListModel`.The `ListElement`'s of the `ListModel` in `GridView` are about 200.Right now I have managed to display the first 35 items in `GridView` scrolling horizontally the `ListView`.What i want to do is to display in each "page" of `ListView`, groups of 35 `ListElements` untill all of them displayed.Which means, in first "page" of `ListView` display the first 35 items of `GridView`, after that , in second "page" the other 35 items etc. while scrolling horizontally.I tryied with the below code to make groups of `DelegateModel` and filter it conditionally in two pages at first, following the answer in this question [Working with delegate model and delegate model group dynamically QML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418032/working-with-delegate-model-and-delegate-model-group-dynamically-qml) :

```
DelegateModel {

        id: visualModel

        delegate: myButton

        model:appsModel

       property var visualIndex: pageList.currentIndex

            groups: [
            DelegateModelGroup {
                id:firstpage
                includeByDefault: true
                name: "firstpage"
            },
            DelegateModelGroup {
                id:secondpage
                includeByDefault: true
                name: "secondpage"
            }
        ]

      onVisualIndexChanged:{

        if(visualIndex===0){
               filterOnGroup: "firstpage";page="first"
        }else if(visualIndex===1){
               filterOnGroup: "secondpage";page="second"
        }else{}
        console.log(visualIndex, page);
    }
      Component.onCompleted:{
                    for( var i = 0;i < items.count;i++ ) {
                    var element = items.get(i).model;
                    if(element.appId > 35) {
                        items.removeGroups(i, 1, "firstpage");
                    }else if(element.appId <= 35 && element.appId > 70) {
                        items.removeGroups(i, 1, "secondpage");
                    }else{}
                }
            }
         }
```

but it does not work.`pageList` is the `ListView`.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: This question feels similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76355483/how-can-i-display-items-across-multiple-pages-when-swiping-in-gridview-qml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DelegateModel is problematic, because, for 6 pages, you would need to create 6 DelegateModelGroups, and, to generalize for n pages, you would need to generalize further.

I highly recommend you engineer a reusable `DelegateModelGroup` that has a `from` and `to` that will help choose different elements from the underlying model to be visible, e.g.

```
    ListView {
        model: colorModel.count / 35
        delegate: GridView {
            model: DelegateModel {
                property from: index * 35
                property to: from + 35
                model: colorModel
                filterOnGroup: "visible"
                // ... heavy lifting needed here
            }
        }
    }
```

That way, for 200 items, it would assign 6 items to the parent ListView, and, for the inner GridView the visual model will choose 35 records from the underlying model to be visible.

Here's a complete working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: page
    ListView {
        width: 640
        height: 480
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: Math.floor((colorModel.count + 34) / 35)
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        clip: true
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem
        delegate: GridView {
            width: ListView.view.width
            height: ListView.view.height
            cellWidth: 70
            cellHeight: 70
            header: Label {
                width: GridView.view.width
                text: `page ${index + 1}`
                horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            }
            model: MyDelegateModel {
                from: index * 35
                to: Math.min(from + 35, colorModel.count)
                model: colorModel
                delegate: MyDelegate { }
            }
        }
    }
    ColorModel {
        id: colorModel
    }
}

// MyDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
DelegateModel {
    property int from: 0
    property int to: 10
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: newItems
            name: "new"
            includeByDefault: true
            onCountChanged: {
                newItems.setGroups(from, to - from, ["new","visible"]);
            }
        },
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "visible" }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "visible"
}

// MyDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Label {
    width: 70
    height: 70
    text: txt
    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    color: Qt.color(col).hslLightness > 0.5 ? "black" : "white"
    wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    background: Rectangle { color: col }
}

// ColorModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListModel {
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            let txt = i;
            let col = Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random()).toString();
            append({txt,col});
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.I have already implemented to my code.The only problem is that Drag and Drop is not working except in the first page.I think there is something to do  with indexing.Anyway I will try harder to solve it.

Comment: How can I get ```visibleIndex``` of ```MyDelegateModel``` from outside of delegate?

Comment: If I were to go via the `newItems` group, I could do something like: `newItems.get(0).visibleIndex`. i.e. from any item from one DelegateModelGroup, I can look up the corresponding item index with respect to another DelegateModelGroup. You can run such code anywhere, you're not constrained to accessing it only from within the delegate code. This is good if you are running multiple DelegateModelGroups and each group have a different filtering/sorting applied to it.

Comment: Lets say in above working example , there is a ```MouseArea``` inside ```GridView```  and on ```onClicked``` signal  I want to get the ```index``` of a certain item.How should I express this ?

Comment: But, wouldn't that MouseArea be in a GridView delegate? From within the delegate, you have `index` and also the item index from the `DelegateModel`, e.g. `DelegateModel.visibleIndex`.